# Api call structure in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

Hello guys i am a beginner at using c# and i am having a bit of a problem correctly consuming an api, i can make the api a json string and view it but that isint of much use to me, so basically i am trying to create a object from a class i created and i want to parse the json data i got into the object so i can do more things with it, but i am having problems with structuring my class to fit the data when it gets parsed.. if you could help that would be fantastic

```
//my function to make the api call
static async Task<Post> MakeRequest()
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Post res = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Post>();

                return res;
            } else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

```
//my class im trying to parse the data into
public class Post
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

```
//example of the api call response
[
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
"body": "quia et suscipit
suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum
reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam
nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "qui est esse",
"body": "est rerum tempore vitae
sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque
fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis
qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
}
]
```

basically i want to know how i can create a post for every object in my api call response and add them to a list or dictionary to be able to consume it better.

Comment: The JSON structure is an array, so change your read to this: `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Post[]>();`

Comment: hey, thanks for the feedback.. but when i try to loop through it doesnt work.. i get an error saying Task<Post[]> does not conatin a public instance definition of "GetEnumerator"

Comment: I expanded my answer below, hopefully that does it.

Comment: @DBankx that means you forgot to `await`. Naturally you can deserialize arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the data structure of the JSON is an array. So if you use `Post[]` as your generic type, it works fine:

```
private static async Task<Post[]> MakeRequestAsync()
{
    using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")))
    using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(msg))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        // Using the System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions method:
        return await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<Post[]>();
        // Using the System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions method:
        // return await resp.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Post[]>();
    }
}
```

I call it as so:

```
var resp = await MakeRequestAsync();
foreach(var r in resp)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {r.Title}");
}
```

And it outputs as you'd expect:

[image: output]

Comment: It would be good clarify where the application is configured to use Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: @AluanHaddad -- I took out that line of text since the new `System.Text.Json`'s `ReadAsAsync` is named `ReadFromJsonAsync`, so it shall be inferred. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That's interesting. However, it's still be possible to configure which deserializer to use.

Comment: @AluanHaddad -- From what I've seen, you stick to one or the other. I added some text to clarify which method you should call based on what extensions are currently installed.

Comment: I definitely agree. I'm just thinking of someone reading this and not seeing the dependency on newtonsoft or where it's registered and being confused. I still voted for this answer

Comment: @AluanHaddad -- thanks, you put me over 3000 rep :)